# import {useHeaderHeight} from '@react-navigation/elements' is working without installing "@react-navigation/elements" specifically

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, node-modules, package.json, react-navigation-v6

I am trying to get the header height in react-native using the useHeaderHeight from "@react-navigation/elements". I already have "@react-navigation/native" package installed and its there in package.json with ^6.0.0 version. Now when I tried to import "@react-navigation/native", without installing that package, it worked for me. When I checked in package.json it is not present there. But when I checked in node_modules, under @react-navigation, I can see the elements folder and thats how it worked.

But my question here is, how its present in node modules without being present in the package.json.

In my project, I shouldn't be installing new package in package.json due to some permission issues.
So can I leave it like that as it is working? Also I want to know whether I will face any problem in future if I don't install that package specifically. Because in Sonar issues it is showing as critical error. But it's working fine in the project.

I tried deleting node_modules and installing again. Still the elements folder is present under @react-navigation. Also, I checked the documentation for the library and didn't find any relevent information.

Comment: Found the answer.
Its because this package is installed as a dependency for @react-navigation/bottom-tabs by default

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the first solution was to downgrade the navigation libs (especially @react-navigation/elements to 1.3.4), but it was hard so I've created a patch to resolve the issue:

@react-navigation+elements+1.3.18.patch

```
diff --git a/node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/lib/commonjs/Header/HeaderBackButton.js b/node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/lib/commonjs/Header/HeaderBackButton.js
index 57fb108..cd0263c 100644
--- a/node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/lib/commonjs/Header/HeaderBackButton.js
+++ b/node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/lib/commonjs/Header/HeaderBackButton.js
@@ -165,7 +165,7 @@ const styles = _reactNative.StyleSheet.create({
       marginVertical: 12,
       resizeMode: 'contain',
       transform: [{
-        scaleX: _reactNative.I18nManager.getConstants().isRTL ? -1 : 1
+        scaleX: _reactNative.I18nManager.isRTL ? -1 : 1
       }]
     },
     default: {
@@ -174,7 +174,7 @@ const styles = _reactNative.StyleSheet.create({
       margin: 3,
       resizeMode: 'contain',
       transform: [{
-        scaleX: _reactNative.I18nManager.getConstants().isRTL ? -1 : 1
+        scaleX: _reactNative.I18nManager.isRTL ? -1 : 1
       }]
     }
   }),
@@ -198,7 +198,7 @@ const styles = _reactNative.StyleSheet.create({
     alignSelf: 'center',
     resizeMode: 'contain',
     transform: [{
-      scaleX: _reactNative.I18nManager.getConstants().isRTL ? -1 : 1
+      scaleX: _reactNative.I18nManager.isRTL ? -1 : 1
     }]
   }
 });
```

And
@react-navigation+stack+6.3.17.patch

```
diff --git a/node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/commonjs/utils/getInvertedMultiplier.js b/node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/commonjs/utils/getInvertedMultiplier.js
index 2abaa86..729edde 100644
--- a/node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/commonjs/utils/getInvertedMultiplier.js
+++ b/node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/commonjs/utils/getInvertedMultiplier.js
@@ -12,9 +12,9 @@ function getInvertedMultiplier(gestureDirection) {
     case 'vertical-inverted':
       return -1;
     case 'horizontal':
-      return _reactNative.I18nManager.getConstants().isRTL ? -1 : 1;
+      return _reactNative.I18nManager.I18nManager.isRTL ? -1 : 1;
     case 'horizontal-inverted':
-      return _reactNative.I18nManager.getConstants().isRTL ? 1 : -1;
+      return _reactNative.I18nManager.I18nManager.isRTL ? -1 : 1;
   }
 }
 //# sourceMappingURL=getInvertedMultiplier.js.map
```